# Replacing NaN/Inf/NA to 0 in a list object

Tags: r

I have a list object in R with NaN/Inf/NA values:

```
dat <- list(a=matrix(c(2,0/0,10/0,NA),nrow=2), b=matrix(c(-3,0,NA,1),nrow=2))
```

How can I replace the NaN/Inf/NA elements to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `replace` the non finite values to 0 by looping over the `list` elements with `lapply`

```
lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, !is.finite(x), 0))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    0
#[2,]    0    0

#$b
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   -3    0
#[2,]    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this by checking if `x%%1==0`:

```
ls <- unlist(dat)
ls[is.na(ls%%1==0)] <- 0
relist(ls, skeleton = dat)

# $a
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    0
# [2,]    0    0

# $b
     # [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   -3    0
# [2,]    0    1
```

Or one-line code as @akrun's answer:

```
lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x%%1==0), 0))
```